# Avro C++: how does one deflate content?

Tags: c++, avro

In avro C (what I have used before), I would write:

```
avro_file_writer_create_with_codec(
    avro_filename, my_schema, &my_writer, "deflate", 0);

// implying that I have to specify "deflate" in other 
// language versions.
```

In avro C++, I read from the documentation that I simply call:

```
avro::DataFileWriter<c::cpx> dfw("test.bin", cpxSchema);
// (copied directly from the Avro C++ documentation)
```

How do I ensure that the avro content is being compressed in the C++ version? (further, in C I typically can acheive performance gains by batching and flushing...can this be done here?)